# Base class as foreign key in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, fluent

Lets say I have some classes:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public decimal Wage { get; set; }

    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I have this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(e => e.PaymentType);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Map(t =>
        {
            t.MapInheritedProperties();
            t.ToTable("Employees");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Employees).WithRequired(e => e.Company).Map(t => t.MapKey("Company_Id"));

}
```

I get two tables for Person and Employee, but I don't like what `MapInheritedProperties()` does by adding the Person properties to the Employee table.

**How do I make the base class(Person) a foreign key?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the base class as a foreing key / navigational property without primary key problems. You need to be using Table per Type or Table per Hierarchy.

In your case using that modelBuilder should do it.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(e => e.PaymentType);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person >().ToTable("Persons");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employees");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Employees).WithRequired(e => e.Company).Map(t => t.MapKey("Company_Id"));
}
```

With this two table will be created. On names Persons will all fields for a person and one "Employees" for all fields for an employee. Both table will share the same primary key

You can get a really detailed explaination on [Mortenza Manavi's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)